# filter rows when all columns greater than a value

Tags: r, dataframe, select, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame and I would like to subset the rows where all columns values meet my cutoff.

here is the data frame:

```
   A B C
1  1 3 5
2  4 3 5
3  2 1 2
```

What I would like to select is rows where all columns are greater than 2.
Second row is what I want to get.

```
[1] 4 3 5
```

here is my code:

```
 subset_data <- df[which(df[,c(1:ncol(df))] > 2),]
```

But my code is not applied on all columns.
Do you have any idea how can I fix this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix my comparing the entire data frame with 2 and then do `rowSums` over it and select only those rows whose value is equal to number of columns in `df`

```
df[rowSums(df > 2) == ncol(df), ]

#  A B C
#2 4 3 5
```

---

A `dplyr` approach using `filter_all` and `all_vars`

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. > 2))

#  A B C
#1 4 3 5
```

`dplyr` > 1.0.0

```
#1. if_all
df %>% filter(if_all(.fns = ~. > 2))

#2. across
df %>% filter(across(.fns = ~. > 2))
```

---

An `apply` approach

```
#Using apply
df[apply(df > 2, 1, all), ]
#Using lapply as shared by @thelatemail
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, `>`, 2)),]
```

Comment: Functional approach for fun - `dat[Reduce(\`&\`, lapply(dat, \`>\`, 2)),]`

Comment: Oh, looks like apply is universally disliked by all data scientists (pandas too)

Comment: @coldspeed In R, `apply` is actually very slow most of the times, especially dealing with data frames as it converts data frame to matrix.

Comment: FYI, `df[rowSums(df > 2) == ncol(df), ]` gave just the values in R 3.6.1. Using the `dplyr` version gave the desired data.frame output.

Comment: @amc that might be because you have only 1 column in the dataframe. Use `df[rowSums(df > 2) == ncol(df), , drop = FALSE]`